The distance between a closed set and a bounded closed set which are disjoint has a positive lower bound (only consider metric space $\mathbf{R}^n$)
Prove/disprove the distance between a closed set and a bounded closed set which are disjoint has a positive lower bound (only consider the metric space $\mathbf{R}^n$)
$A$ is a closed set in $\mathbf{R}^{n}$, $B$ is a bounded closed set in $\mathbf{R}^{n}$, and $A\cap B=\emptyset$. How to prove/disprove there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $\mathbf{x}\in A$, $B(\mathbf{x},\epsilon)$ is disjoint from $B$?
My question is related to “Zero distance between a closed set and a bounded closed set which are disjoint in a metric space”, but they are two different questions. My question only considers the metric space $\mathbf{R}^{n}$, but the question in the link considers an arbitrary metric space. Actually, I only have learnt topology of $\mathbf{R}^{n}$.
It seems the question in the link tells us that we can disprove this result in arbitrary metric space.However, only considering the metric space $\mathbf{R}^{n}$, we can prove this result, which means we can prove there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $\mathbf{x}\in A, B(\mathbf{x},\epsilon)$ is disjoint from $B$. Here is my try:
$B$ is compact in $\mathbf{R}^{n}$. We define a function $f\colon B\rightarrow\mathbf{R}$ by $f(\mathbf{x})=d(\mathbf{x},A)$. Here $d(\mathbf{x},A)$ is the distance between the point $\mathbf{x}$ and the set $A$. For all $\mathbf{x}\in B$, $f(\mathbf{x})>0$. $f$ is a continuous function on the compact set $B$. As a result, $f$ has a minimum value $\epsilon>0$ on $B$. Finally, there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $\mathbf{x}\in A$, $B(\mathbf{x},\epsilon)$ is disjoint from $B$.
Here are my questions:
(i) We can prove there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $\mathbf{x}\in A$, $B(\mathbf{x},\epsilon)$ is disjoint from $B$ in the metric $\mathbf{R}^{n}$ and my “try” above is correct. Am I right?
(ii) We can disprove there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $\mathbf{x}\in A$, $B(\mathbf{x},\epsilon)$ is disjoint from $B$ in arbitrary metric space (the question in the link tells me). Am I right?

@studyhard Your proof includes the "hard part", which is that $f$ is continuous. How do you know that $f$ is continuous? I would include a proof of that.

@Balajisb: the key is that $B$ is compact. Otherwise the result is not true. For instance, in $\mathbb R^2$ you can take $A={(0,x):\ x}$ and $B={(x,1/x):\ x>0}$. Both sets are closed, and the distance between them is zero.

@Balajisb: of course. When one of them is bounded, being closed, it is compact and the distance does exist. That's precisely the crucial aspect, not just that they are closed.

@Balajisb: no, it's not true in that generality. Like I said, the crucial property is compactness. And in an arbitrary metric space, there are closed and bounded sets which are not compact. A fairly basic example of this (where both sets are closed and bounded) was given in the answer linked in OP's  question.

@Balajisb: $\ell^\infty$ is complete, so the example occurs in a complete metric space. And it's a vector space over $\mathbb C$, so it's certainly connected (as it's path connected). As for the example, take those $A,B$ in that example and form $A'$ by joining the $e_n$ with segments and similarly form $B'$. Then $A',B'$ are disjoint, connected, closed, and the distance between them is zero.

@Balajisb: the same idea works. In $\ell^\infty$ take $A$ to be the closed unit ball, and
$$
B=\Big{x\in\ell^\infty:\ 2\geq x_n\geq1+\frac1n\ \text{ for all $n$}\Big}.
$$ Then $A$ is bounded and closed, $B$ is closed, both are the closure of their interiors, $A\cap B=\varnothing$, and the distance between them is zero.

Your argument is fine. What happens in an arbitrary metric space is that it is not true that a closed and bounded set is compact.
For another proof when $B$ is compact, if you  had a sequence $\{b_n\}\subset B$ with $d(b_n,A)\to0$, the compactness of $B$ allows you to choose a convergent subsequence. So there exists $b\in B $ and a sequence $\{c_n\}\subset B $ with $c_n\to b $ and $d(c_n,A)\to0$. If $\{a_n\}\subset A$ with $d(c_n,a_n)\to0$, then
$$
d(b,a_n)\leq d(b,c_n)+d (c_n,a_n)\to0.
$$
This shows that $b\in\overline A=A$, contradicting that $A\cap B=\emptyset$.
The above proof has the slight advantage that it does not require you to prove that your $f$ is continuous.
