Confusions about Theorem 16.3 in Munkres' "Analysis on Manifolds"
In Munkres' "Analysis on Manifolds", page 139, Theorem 16.3, it states: Because each $\mathbf{x}\in A$ has a neighborhood on which $\lambda(\mathbf{x})$ equals a finite sum of $C^{\infty}$function, $\lambda(\mathbf{x})$ is of class $C^{\infty}$.
Here are my questions:
(i) Using the argument above, we can only get “$\lambda(\mathbf{x})$ is of class $C^{\infty}$ on $A$” rather than “$\lambda(\mathbf{x})$ is of class $C^{\infty}$ on $\mathbf{R}^{n}$”. So, I think the proof in Munkres' book is incomplete. How to prove “$\lambda(\mathbf{x})$ is of class $C^{\infty}$ on $\mathbf{R}^{n}$”? Especially, if $\mathbf{x}\in\mathrm{Bd}A$, how to prove $\lambda(\mathbf{x})$ is of class $C^{\infty}$at $\mathbf{x}$? The most difficult part is the boundary of $A$.
(ii) $\phi_{i}$ is a function from $\mathbf{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbf{R}$ and Munkres says “(5) The functions $\phi_{i}$ are of class $C^{\infty}$”. It means “The functions $\phi_{i}$ are of class $C^{\infty}$ on $\mathbf{R}^{n}$” rather than “The functions $\phi_{i}$ are of class $C^{\infty}$ on $A$”. Am I right?
This a question from Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds. I show you the whole context of the question below. I have trouble understanding the statements with red lines.


The series $\lambda(x)$ is only considered on $A$.  Why do want to do know something about it for $x \notin A$?

@PaulFrost, $\lambda(\mathbf{x})$ is defined on $\mathbf{R}^{n}$ since all the $\psi(\mathbf{x})$ are defined on $\mathbf{R}^{n}$. Moreover, $\phi_{i}(\mathbf{x})=\psi_{i}(\mathbf{x})/\lambda(\mathbf{x})$ is also a function defined on $\mathbf{R}^{n}$. Check Munkres says “$\phi_{i}\colon\mathbf{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbf{R}$”.

OP, this definition doesn't work in the strictest sense because $\lambda$ equals $0$ outside of $A$, including the boundary. The point is that it makes sense on $A$, gives you a compactly supported smooth function on $A$, and then because it's compactly supported in an open set you can extend it by $0$ to both give it a proper meaning and have a smooth function. You don't need regularity of $\lambda$ on the boundary because you don't "see" it through the functions considered.

Think of it this way: what prevents $\lambda$ from going to $\infty$ when it goes to the boundary from inside $A$? Why would $\lambda$ be continuous there, let alone smooth?

@BrunoB Wow, it is a new problem. We need to modify the definition of $\phi_{i}$. Define $\phi_{i}$ in this way: $\phi_{i}(\mathbf{x})=\psi_{i}(\mathbf{x})/\lambda(\mathbf{x})$ on $A$ and $\phi_{i}(\mathbf{x})=0$ on $\mathbf{R}^{n}-A$. Am I right？

The supports of the $\psi_i$s, and thus of the $\varphi_i$s, are contained in $A$, so that, almost by the definition of a compactly supported smooth function, on $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus A$ you can extend the $\varphi_i$s by $0$ and still have $C^\infty$ functions.
You don't need to prove that $\lambda$ is $C^\infty$ on the boundary of $A$ because all the $\varphi_i$s vanish between their support and said boundary.
A standard fact is that given an open set $U$ and a compact set $K \subset U$, the distance $d(K, U^c) = d(K, \partial U)$ is strictly positive, so that you have some leeway between the support of each $\varphi_i$ and the boundary of $A$, making it so that extending $\varphi_i$ by $0$ gives you a function that's $C^\infty$ on the boundary points because it's already $0$ on a neighborhood of said boundary.
The main point I'd like to get across is that the regularity of $\lambda$ at the boundary doesn't matter for the regularity of the $\varphi_i$s because you just don't "see" it thanks to the compact supports.

If $\mathbf{x}\in\mathrm{Bd}A$, how to prove $\lambda(\mathbf{x})$ is of class $C^{\infty}$ at $\mathbf{x}$? The most difficult part is the boundary of $A$.

@studyhard I've edited the answer, hopefully it is to your liking.

However, I just want to prove $\lambda$ is $C^{\infty}$ on the boundary of $A$ rigorously. $\phi_{i}(\mathbf{x})=\psi_{i}(\mathbf{x})/\lambda(\mathbf{x})$. If we want to conclude $\phi_{i}$ is of class $C^{\infty}$ on $\mathbf{R}^{n}$, we need $\lambda$ is of class $C^{\infty}$on $\mathbf{R}^{n}$. Especially, we need $\lambda$ is $C^{\infty}$ on the boundary of A

@studyhard That's only a sufficient condition, as I tried to tell you. You don't need any regularity on $\lambda$ outside of $A$ because $\psi$ and thus $\phi$ will vanish way before the boundary.

I want to make sure that I understand your approach. We only need to know $\lambda$ is of class $C^{\infty}$ on $A$ and it is enough! Then, we get $\phi_{i}$ is of class $C^{\infty}$ on $A$. $\phi_{i}$ is vanish on $\mathbf{R}^{n}-S_{i}$, so $\phi_{i}$ is of class $C^{\infty}$ on $\mathbf{R}^{n}-S_{i}$. As a result, $\phi_{i}$ is of class $C^{\infty}$ on $A\cup {\mathbf{R}^{n}-S_{i}}=\mathbf{R}^{n}$. Am I right?

@studyhard Yes, that's exactly it! I do understand why it wouldn't be natural, but that's the type of reasoning that comes back and back again with compactly supported functions so you'll get used to it at some point. To make it rigorous you do have to use the fact that $d(K, U^c) > 0$ as mentioned in my answer so I'd suggest trying to see for yourself why that's true or looking up a proof. A non-compactly supported function might vanish at the boundary but maybe not at all orders, preventing you from getting a smooth extension.

It's an amazing answer! Thank you so much!

I know that fact! It is Theorem 4.6 in Munkres' book! I'm familiar with its proof, which is similar to the proof I write in this question:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4977123/the-distance-between-a-closed-set-and-a-bounded-closed-set-which-are-disjoint-ha.

The proof of Theorem 16.3 is in fact a bit sloppy.
The functions $\psi_i$ are defined on $\mathbb R^n$ and the series $\lambda(x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \psi_i(x)$ converges for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$. We have $\lambda(x) > 0 $ for $x \in A$ and $\lambda(x) = 0$ for $x \notin A$.
Thus the definition $\phi_i(x) = \dfrac{\psi_i(x)}{\lambda(x)}$ only makes sense for $x \in A$. Let us call this map $\phi_i^A : A \to \mathbb R$. We have to extend these maps to continuous maps $\phi_i : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$.
Clearly $\psi_i$ and  $\phi_i^A$ have the same carrier $S_i$ which is a compact subset of $A$. A continuous extension $\phi_i : \mathbb  R^n \to \mathbb R$ of $\phi_i^A$ is therefore obtained by defining $\phi_i(x) = 0$ for $x \notin A$. If $\operatorname{cl} A \ne \mathbb R^n$ there are also other continuous extensions of $\phi_i^A$, but every continuous extension must necessarily satisfy $\phi_i(x) = 0$ for $x \in \operatorname{bd} A$.
The function $\mu(x)  = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \phi_i(x)$ is the characteristic function of the set $A$ which is not continuous at the points of $\operatorname{bd} A$.
But as I already said in a comment, it is completely irrelevant what happens outside of $A$. Perhaps Munkres should better have written

There exists a sequence $\phi_1, \phi_2, \ldots$ of continuous functions $\phi_i : A \to \mathbb R^n$ such that:

